# How to set animation in CollectionView cell only for one indexPath.row item?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I have UICollectionView and I want to start image animation for only one cell. But the problem is that when i add this animation affects on more item than one cell. 
Here is the code:

```
func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return arrays.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        //do the animation
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the cells are being reused. Think of it this way, if you have 100 different objects but only display 2 at a time, the collectionview will only create, say, about 4 cells. It does this to save memory and to speed up performance

So if you have Cell A and B on screen that show details from array[0] and array[1] respectively and then start scrolling, the next cells that will appear will be C and D that show array[2] and array[3]. However, if you keep scrolling, A and B will appear again, but this time it will show you  information for array[4] and array[5]. Then if you keep scrolling, it will show cell C and D again, but with infrmation for array[6] and array[7]. This is the idea of reusing cells

So in your case what is happening is that you're applying an animation to Cell A, but then when you scroll you keep seeing this animation on "other cells". These other cells are in actual fact Cell A being reused.

The solution is for you to stop the animation on a cell whenever `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` is called i.e

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    /* 
    Stop animation in case the cell is already being animated
    */
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        //do the animation
```